# Python module error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.analytics'

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

I have installed the google-analytics-data module as instructed in the Quick Start guide, and last week was able to call the API with no issue. This morning I am getting an error when importing the needed packages: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.analytics'. Anyone else having a similar issue?

Comment: Please include the part of your code which is calling the api

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.